# How to find the domain of $\ln(\sqrt{x+y})$

Tags: calculus

Can you please tell me if I am correct?

$\ln(\sqrt{x+y})$

Df = { (x,y) ∈ $R^2$ : $x+y$ $\ge$ 0 $\land$ $\sqrt{x+y} > 0$ }

⟺ Df = { (x,y) ∈ $R^2$ : $y\ge$ $-x$ $\land$ $\sqrt{x+y} > 0$ }

Is that it? If not, where am I wrong?

Comment: Ok, but you have not finished : $\sqrt{x} > 0$ if and only if $x > 0$.

Comment: You just need $x+y > 0$

Comment: And you did a misuse of the symbol $\iff$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not wrong. Indeed, the domain is
$$\{(x,y)|x+y>0\}$$
Because $x+y\geq0$ and $\sqrt{x+y}>0$ it's $x+y>0$.

Comment: @Jaideep Khare No! Hi wrote $x+y\geq0$ and $\sqrt{x+y}>0$, which gives $x+y>0$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read intersection of both of them.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to say that a function comes with a domain. So, this question doesn't make any sense. A better way to ask this question would be:

Find the maximal domain (subset of the real numbers) on which we can define the function given by $$f(x,y) = \ln(\sqrt{x+y})$$

There are two things that have to be satisified:

$$\sqrt{x+y} > 0$$ because otherwise $\ln$ isn't well defined.

and $$x+y \geq 0$$

because otherwise the $\sqrt{}$ isn't well defined.

To satisfy these two statements, we must have $x + y > 0$

Hence, the domain is:

$$D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}|x+y>0\}$$